# Reuse Opportunity Snapshot

Tags: reporting, opportunity, snapshot

I've got an opportunity snapshot running monthly and it's working well.

I want to run the exact data weekly as well but don't want to create a new model.

Is it possible to pass a default/text value into a snapshot without having that info on the opportunity?

Any ideas on how to make that happen?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not having that info on opportunity'? Is it related list? If so, you can try Doug's workaround ['Filter Related Lists without Code'](https://douglascayers.com/2015/11/18/salesforce-filter-related-lists-without-code/), but with Snapshot Object's limitation I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: Whether the snapshot is run weekly or monthly isn't stored on the opportunity. Everything between the two snapshots is identical other than the cadence

Comment: it can be added as related list on the page layout

Comment: I understand I can add it but I'm trying to set its value via the snapshot execution. So when a snapshot runs monthly the value is set to monthly, if it runs weekly then weekly

Comment: Apparently, I don't understand what exactly you are asking...

Comment: I just tried in my org, and it seems like you can have a bucket field on the report that you can map to Text field on snapshot object

Comment: How do you set up a bucket in the report that shows whether the snapshot is run monthly or weekly?

Comment: You would have to setup a different schedule, and in that schedule you can have different fields mapping - e.g. have one to populate the field, and keep it null on other snapshot run, or populate with a different field value. You also have a simple formula field ="Weekly" on Opportunity

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the same data weekly and monthly, you should be able to use the created date field on the records being created by the snapshot to include/exclude the data you are interested in.  If needed, you could add a formula field to the object you are storing these on, which could evaluate created date to determine which category it falls into (the formula used would depend on whether monthly runs on the beginning, middle, or the end of the month)

That said, when you run a snapshot you can map the snapshot name to the name field on the record being created (or I believe to any other text field on the object).  So if you actually wanted to schedule the weekly and monthly runs separately, then you can just name them appropriately and map that to a text field on the object.

A screenshot from a snapshot where I have done so is below.

[image: analytics snapshot field mappings]